# How do you directly convert a complex number, in quadmath, to a string and vice versa?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, complex-numbers

Is there a way to directly convert a __complex128 number, in quadmath, to a string and vice versa? I can do convert the real and imaginary parts, individually, to strings via quadmath_snprintf. strtoflt128 will convert a string representing a real number to __float128. But I have not found how to convert a string representing a complex number to __complex128. Nor even how  the string should configured.